# React native error: JSX element type 'AppLoading' does not have any construct or call signatures?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am creating a react native expo application and trying to import some custom fonts. I want the app to render a `AppLoading` component when the fonts are loading. However, when I insert it into the code and run it, it returns an error saying:

`JSX element type 'AppLoading' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Code:

```js
// Importing packages
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import redux, { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducers from "./redux/index";
import AppLoading from "expo";
import Router from "./Router";
import loadFonts from "./fonts";

// App component
const App:React.FC = () => {
  // Redux store
  const store: redux.Store = createStore(reducers);

  // State
  let [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (loaded) {
    // Render app
    return (
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {/* Router */}
            <Router />
          </View>
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={loadFonts} onFinish={() => setLoaded(true)} />
    );
  }
};

// Export app
export default App;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import AppLoading from "expo";
```

That would assume that `AppLoading` is the default export of the entire expo package, which is definitely not the case.

As per [the documention](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/app-loading/) you need to import `AppLoading` like this:

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! you are a life saver!